# How to speed up lag variable creation?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, time-series

Lets say we have a dataframe and want to create many different lag variables on every column, what/how is the most efficient way to do this?

Current Solution:

```
Columns = [Some Columns]

for col in Columns:

    d1[col + '_LagEWM_5'] = d1.groupby(['Player_id']).apply(lambda x: 
    x[col].shift(1).ewm(span=5).mean()).reset_index(0,drop=True)

    d1[col + '_LagMax_5'] = d1.groupby(['Player_id']).apply(lambda x: x[col].shift(1).rolling(5, 
    min_periods=1).max()).reset_index(0,drop=True)

    df[col + '_LagMin_5'] = df.groupby(['Player_id']).apply(lambda x: x[col].shift(1).rolling(5, 
    min_periods=1).min()).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

With a reproducible example, it would be simpler, anyway, an expensive part of this code is **d1.groupby(['Player_id'])**, this can be done one time only, this will speed up a lot.
Another hint, a little bit tricky, is to do the *.apply(lambda x: x[col].shift(1)* only one time and create inside each group the 3 new columns. Finally append all groups.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found a faster solution.

For each lag variable you can do this:

```
Columns = [Some Columns]

shifted_var = df.groupby(["Player_id"])[Columns].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1).ewm(span=5).mean()).reset_index(0,drop=True)

df = df.join(shifted_var.rename(columns=lambda x: x+'_LagEWM_5'))
```

The expensive part was looping through each column in the original solution. Let me know if anyone has a better solution